# type int32_t for loop variable declaration

Tags: c++

I've got a for loop declaring a variable of type int32_t and im not really sure why it is used as opposed to just type int. I understand the difference between the two but im not sure if int32_t is needed here.

```
  void AlarmProcess::AlarmProcess_alarm_Timer_1Sec()
{
    //Timer function called every 50ms
    static AlarmParams alarm_Params;
    //Update LED and buzzer
    //Buzzer is on for 1 second and off for 10 seconds then repeats.
    //Why define index as int32_t?
    for(int32_t i32_Index = 0;i32_Index < AlarmProcess_getInstance()->alarm_Parameter_List.Count; i32_Index++)
    {
        //Check for non latching mode
        if(AlarmProcess_getInstance()->alarm_Parameter_List.alarm_Parameter[i32_Index].Latching == false)
        {
            //Get channel number
            int32_t i32_Channel_Num = AlarmProcess_getInstance()->alarm_Parameter_List.alarm_Parameter[i32_Index].Channel_Number;
            //Get alarm detection type
            int32_t i32_Detection = AlarmProcess_getInstance()->alarm_Parameter_List.alarm_Parameter[i32_Index].Detection;
            //Check detection type and channel number mapping
            if((i32_Detection == HIGH && AlarmProcess_getInstance()->m_mapHighAlarmRaised[i32_Channel_Num] == true) ||
                (i32_Detection == LOW && AlarmProcess_getInstance()->m_mapLowAlarmRaised[i32_Channel_Num] == true) ||
                (i32_Detection == WINDOW_IN && AlarmProcess_getInstance()->m_mapWindowInAlarmRaised[i32_Channel_Num] == true) ||
                (i32_Detection == WINDOW_OUT && AlarmProcess_getInstance()->m_mapWindowOutAlarmRaised[i32_Channel_Num] == true))
            {
                // check for buzzer on or off
                if(s_bIsActivate == true)
                {
                    //Check for one second elapse
                    if((s_i32alarmTimerCount[i32_Channel_Num]) >= ONE_SECOND)
                    {
                        RETAILMSG(DEBUG_ALARM_PROCESS,(_T("Buzzer off:%d\r\n"),s_i32alarmTimerCount));
                        //Update counter variable
                        s_i32alarmTimerCount[i32_Channel_Num] = 0;

                        //Get alarm settings
                        AlarmProcess_getInstance()->b_AlarmProcess_GetAlarmsettingDetails(i32_Index,alarm_Params);

                        // Turn off the the buzzer
                        b_AlarmProcess_control_Buzzer(false,ZERO);
                        // update the flag
                        s_bIsActivate = false;
                    }
                    //Increment timer count variable
                    s_i32alarmTimerCount[i32_Channel_Num] += GPT_TIMER_RESOLUTION;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Check for 10 second elapse
                    if((s_i32alarmTimerCount[i32_Channel_Num]) >= TEN_SECOND)   
                    {
                        // Reinitialize the counter variable
                        s_i32alarmTimerCount[i32_Channel_Num] = 0;
                        RETAILMSG(DEBUG_ALARM_PROCESS,(_T("Buzzer ON:%d\r\n"),s_i32alarmTimerCount));

                        //Check if buzzer need to be enabled
                        if(s_bIsBuzzer == true)
                        {
                            //Enable buzzer
                            b_AlarmProcess_control_Buzzer(true,i32_Detection);

                        }

                        // update the flag
                        s_bIsActivate = true;
                    }
                    //increment timer count variable
                    s_i32alarmTimerCount[i32_Channel_Num] += GPT_TIMER_RESOLUTION;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And Alarm_Parameter_List class is the following:

```
class Alarm_Parameter_List
    {
    public :
        Alarm_Parameters alarm_Parameter[50]; 
        int Count; 
        Alarm_Parameter_List(){ Count = 0;} 
    };

    }
```

I just dont understand why int32_t is used instead of int.

Comment: Answers to this question are likely to all fall into the "we can't read the original coder's mind" category.

Comment: Since `AlarmProcess_getInstance()->alarm_Parameter_List.Count` is of type `int`, I would have used `int` myself.

Comment: @RSahu: But `int32_t` is a _signed_ integer type.

Comment: @TonyK, today is my day to be partially blind :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is simply a bad code. Either data member `Count` should be declared with type specifier `int32_t` or `int32_Index` should be declared with type `int` (and have some other name). Otherwise the code only confuses readers.

As for me then I would declare Count as having type `size_t` provided that it may not store negative numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Do not assume that all C platforms use 32-bit ints.  This code looks like it might be for an embedded controller in an alarm clock.  Embedded controllers are more likely to have 8-bit or possibly 16-bit processors with a shorter native `int` type.

Comment: But the loop variable should always be an `int`, because `Count` is an `int`.

Comment: The code is for an embedded device, but it is not an alarm clock. It has an alarm functionality to notify a user of a certain threshold condition is met. Likewise, it is using a freescale iMX537 microprocessor and is using WinCE7 for the OS and application base.